# Reemplazar valor vacío en array Android

Tags: java, android, jsonobject

El resultado de la API devuelve uno de los valores vacío, el valor corresponde a una imagen. Como viene vació la aplicación se cae. Cómo puedo reemplazar el valor vacío, que es la URL de una imagen por una imagen desde la carpeta drawable?

```
            if(obj.optString("status").equals("200")){

            ArrayList<ModelChannels> ModelChannelsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray dataArray  = obj.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {

                ModelChannels ModelChannels = new ModelChannels();
                JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                if (dataobj.getString("name") == null){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, obj.optString("message")+"ffffff", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                ModelChannels.setImage_url(dataobj.getString("image_url"));
                ModelChannels.setName(dataobj.getString("name"));
                ModelChannels.setStream_base_url(dataobj.getString("stream_base_url"));
                ModelChannels.setTwitter_url(dataobj.getString("twitter_url"));

                if (dataobj.getString("name").isEmpty()) {
                    **IMAGEN DE REEMPLAZO**
                } else{
                    ModelChannels.setImage_url(dataobj.getString("image_url"));
                }

                ModelChannelsArrayList.add(ModelChannels);

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo resolví en el Adpater con esta condición:

```
   if (dataModelArrayList.get(position).getImage_url().isEmpty()) {
        holder.iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_xl);
    }else{
        Picasso.get().load(dataModelArrayList.get(position).getImage_url()).into(holder.iv);
    }
```

Comment: En ocasiones puede venir un valor con espacios " " o un valor que no es una url, agregué una respuesta para detectar estos casos, insertar una cadena vacía "" y en el adapter puedes validar como lo realizas aquí con isEmpty(), saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente estas validando con el valor de la llave "name", en realidad deberías validar con el valor de la llave "image_url":

```
 //if (dataobj.getString("name").isEmpty()) {
   if (dataobj.getString("image_url").isEmpty()) {
     **IMAGEN DE REEMPLAZO**
     } else{
       ModelChannels.setImage_url(dataobj.getString("image_url"));
  }
```

En tu caso esta usando `Picasso`, por lo que comentas que se cierra la app, es precisamente porque trata de cargar un valor de url vacío o null, para esto tienes que validar si el valor es null o es una cadena vacía.

Lo ideal es validar de esta forma, además de validar un valor null, valida el caso de espacios, y si el contenido no inicia con "http",  esto lo puedes realizar desde el parser:

```
 if(dataobj.isNull("image_url") || dataobj.optString("image_url").trim().isEmpty() || !dataobj.optString("image_url").startsWith("http")){
  //No define imagen   
  ModelChannels.setImage_url("");            
} else{
  ModelChannels.setImage_url(dataobj.getString("image_url"));
}
```

En tu adapter puedes validar como lo estas tratando:

```
if (dataModelArrayList.get(position).getImage_url().isEmpty()) {
        holder.iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_xl);
}else{
        Picasso.get().load(dataModelArrayList.get(position).getImage_url()).into(holder.iv);
}
```